# Animate items added/removed to a jQuery Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I have an accordion on my page and I'm polling the server with Ajax requests for updates that should be added or removed to the accordion.

Now I wonder if there is some way to Animate adding and removing items in the Accordion? Or any other way that will make it look a bit nicer then just a plain refresh.

Thanks,
Stefan

Comment: Well if your accordion has closed sections, if you added to a closed section you wouldn't see it. Otherwise, I'd probably use fadeIn() or slideUp() or similar

Comment: So, If I add an extra item to an Accordion I can fade that in? I'm not sure how to add an item to an Accordion and at same time fade in the new header.

Answer (score 0):

Well a short answer would be: yes there are ways to make a bit nicer, but what exactly are you after? Maybe take a look at [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)

Comment: I'm aware of of jQuery UI as the Accordion I'm talking about are included in that package. My question is how I can animate removing and adding items to an accordion.

Comment: fade, slide, check Nivo Slider and see if you can adapt the transitions for your accordion